# PHP merge 2 arrays similar to SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: php

I want to merge 2 arrays and obtain a single array, but merging them based on array 1 [id_dueno] = array 2 [id].
It will be an equivalent of using JOIN ON in MYSQL.

I cant just array_merge(array1,array2). Sometimes I receive many arrays so I have to merge based on IDs

**ARRAY 1**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [nombre_propiedad] => casa 
                [id_dueno] => 2
                [direccion] => direccion 321
                [id_arrendatario] => 1
                [rol] => 10-12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [nombre_propiedad] => Edificio 
                [id_dueno] => 1
                [direccion] => direccion 123
                [id_arrendatario] => 2
                [rol] => 47-18
            )
)
```

**ARRAY 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nombre_dueno] => dueño1
            [ciudad_dueno] => TEMUCO
            [direccion_dueno] => Vicuna Mackena 123
            [rut_dueno] => 11118000-0
            [ultimo_recibo] => 41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nombre_dueno] => duenño2
            [ciudad_dueno] => TEMUCO
            [direccion_dueno] => Vicuña Mackenna 321
            [rut_dueno] => 111314-6
            [ultimo_recibo] => 3
        )
)
```

**Desired result**

```
Array
    (
        [nombre_propiedad] => casa 
        [id_dueno] => 2
        [direccion] => direccion 321
        [id_arrendatario] => 1
        [rol] => 10-12
        [id] => 2
        [nombre_dueno] => duenño2
        [ciudad_dueno] => TEMUCO
        [direccion_dueno] => Vicuña Mackenna 321
        [rut_dueno] => 111314-6
        [ultimo_recibo] => 3
    )
```

Comment: My mistake, i´ll edit the question

Comment: Why does your result only have 1 row? There are two `id_dueno` in array 1, and they each have a corresponding `id` in array 2, shouldn't there be entries in the result for each of them?

Comment: `array_merge()` doesn't try to find related rows in the inputs.

Comment: Anyway, the general approach for things like this is to turn one of the arrays into an associative array that uses the ID as its key. Then you loop through the other array, and merge the element with the corresponding key into the element of the result.

Comment: Yes, sadly array_merge() is not usefull alone. I will try your approach @Barmar thanks!